# Cauchy principal value for an integral with poles on path of integration

Tags: contour-integration, complex-integration, cauchy-principal-value

I have a problem with a complex integral for which poles are on the path of integration. For that, I took the integral and "disassembled" it into segments with an infinitesimal step from the poles, and I ended up with the principal value of the integral, consisting of three line segments, and two residues that represent pole contribution. I resolved all the integrals and residues but one: I am trying to work out the integral for the [line segment between two poles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhdtM.png), but seem to be stuck. I can't use the Residue theorem here, and since the integral is not from infinity to infinity I don't see how trying to assess limits of the integral could be helpful. I easily may be missing something, but I'm not sure what.

Could anyone provide any guidance on how this works? intuitively I know this integral should go to zero, but I don't see how/where

Comment: The limit exists but is not equal to zero:
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{-\pi/2 + \epsilon}^{\pi/2 - \epsilon}
 \frac {e^{i z}} {\pi^2 - (2 z)^2} dz =
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac {\cos z} {\pi^2 - (2 z)^2} dz =
\frac {\operatorname {Si}(\pi)} {2 \pi}.$$